# Should I use Excel or Access

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, database-design

Currently I'm attempting to determine how to easily be able to enter data either in Excel or Access. I'd use the Data form tool in excel however I'm using a scanner that's configured to send an enter command after a successful scan so it would move to the next cell.

```
Serial Number   Employee    Time
    123          Brian  8/20/13 8:49:21 PM
    213          Brian  8/20/13 8:49:21 PM
    334          Nick   8/20/13 8:49:21 PM
```

I'd like to be able to have an accurate time that the serial number was scanned. As it is right now every time a change was made on the sheet the time updates which really defeats the purpose. I'm currently using this formula:

```
 =IF(A2<>"",NOW(),"")
```

I'd also like to be able to  make the employee name able to be changed but also stay the same during the time when that person is scanning the items. I tried just referencing a dropdown list but, when that field changes so does the rest of the employee field.

I'm guessing that this would be best suited for Access because eventually this will be located in different locations and I'd need to be able to correlate the data.Honestly, I'm just too unfamiliar with it to be able to really create something amazing and have it work.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: well if you want to be able to create multiple data options within the database, go with access, but if you're looking to move it from place to place, use excel. Excel is more of a simple Access in a sense, but access is more intuitive for databases.

Comment: Could you clarify your application a bit please? Your scanner inputs what data -- just the serial number? If so, you can have a reference list of employees, and create a macro to enter the employee name for that serial number (and the time) as fixed cells -- not formulas -- when a new serial number is added which means you can change the name associated with an employee number without changing past entries. It also eliminates the issues with using `=NOW()`. What other data are you correlating with this list?

Comment: The only data that the scanner inputs would be serial numbers from a barcode. Later down the line, this list is correlated with reports generated from a different program to determine if it has been worked on or not. The hangup is that the scanning has to be fluid, as in, it will cost a lot of time overall to be have to enter in their name every time they scan rather than doing it once per session. It doesn't sound like much, but when this will have to see 10k+ hard drives a week it adds up..quick. That's why I'm trying to streamline the whole process if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your serial numbers most likely correlate to some articles and you already think of multiple locations and users, I would suggest using Access.

All this leans more to a datebase, which might not be that intuitive to set up for you as excel would be, but in the end it is way more solid and easier to handle, when it comes to catching dublicates, and making queries.

However, it can be done both ways. But not using `now()` - because this function would update your time, whenever recalculated. That is why you get the same time over and over.

You would have to create and call a function, which inserts the time as fixed text, not as dynamic content.

On Access however, using a now-function as the default value for a field would work, as the database-entry would be the value not the function.

For Excel you would have to ramp up this function and could create/activate a keylistener, when activating a new Worker:

```
'This code goes into a VBA-Module
'and can be access on a Worksheet calling =myScan("test")
Public Function myScan(strWorker As String)
    Table1.Cells(2, 1) = "1"
    Table1.Cells(2, 2) = strWorker
    Table1.Cells(2, 3) = Now()
End Function
```

The Serial-Number can be derived from the row. The main Problem would be to stay on the current/next row to paste the data in.

But you could - just for instance - create an Excel Dialog to select a Worker, then activate a Scan mode and scan ... you could even connect to a Web or Access database, not storing the data in excel, which I would highly recommend ;)

### Edit

```
'This code works, when you place it as the VBA-Code of your worksheet
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'react only on changes on column A
    If (Target.Column = 1) Then
        'react only on changes on column A when the row is greater than 5
        If (Target.Row > 5) Then
            'use the current time for Bx
            Me.Cells(Target.Row, 2) = Now()
            'use the user-name from C2 in Cx
            Me.Cells(Target.Row, 3) = Me.Cells(2, 3)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Use `ALT+F11` open the VBA-Editor and choose the table-object you want to use and place the code above into it, than save as a Macro-Excel-Dokument.

Your worksheet should look like this:

[image]

It will automatically update, whenever you change something from A6-Ax.

Comment: This sound very promising I'll try it tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The code that you posted. How exactly is this meant to be used. I've never really dealt with VBA before so I'm a bit unsure. Trying to produce results on my own has proved challenging.

Comment: Also, the serial numbers are already known, I just have to put them in.

Comment: Ok, I think I know now, what you are looking for: you scan, and as you scan column A gets serial numbers put in and progresses to the next row, while this happens, you want to set a timestamp and the name of the current scanner-user ... correct?

Comment: Ok, based on my new assuption and that your scanner "types in" the serial-nr and end with an enter - this should work or at least it should be a good starting point for you ...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is; Excel is NOT a database.  If you're going to be reporting on data, and it's going to contain a LOT of data, don't even consider Excel.  It's a SPREADSHEET, not a DATABASE.